# MEMU Emulator automation via command line (touch) action

Tags: android-emulator

I was able to start the image using

```
memuc start -i  11
```

and start the desired app using

```
memuc startapp -i   11  com.camelgames
```

but I couldn't find any refrence on how to mimic mouse clicks (touch)? Can you help?

I found no material or guide on how to mimic touch event so I tried nothing so far